How to do a initial condition sweep in Simulink?
enter image description here
I need to make a initial condition sweep on the position integrator (pos), 20 different values in [-1.5,1.5], and also a sweep on the gains. I don't know how to even start. I need to visualize all of them in the phase diagram XY Graph.
I tried introducing a vector in the initial condition, but it didn't work.
